# RJ-45 with only four wires?

Tags: networking

Dig through a junk drawer, I find a long cable with RJ-45 on each end.  Definitely **not** RJ-11.  It has only four wires.  What might it have been used for?

I'm not expert on wired ethernet, but in forty years of tech work, I've seen only six and eight wire connectors, mostly eight.  This is the first time I've seen four on RJ-45.

Comment: RJ-45 with 4 pins only, or RJ-45 with 8 pins, but only 4 are connected to the cable?

Comment: role of sush a cable  depends on the wires order  it can be serial (not ethernet) use for example but using rj45 plugs, it can be tokenring it can be many things look at google image with "rj45 4 wires" search  maybe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ethernet networking up to 100Mbps only 2 pairs are used, so you can (fully outside specs, but working) wire 1 pair to 1-2 pins and second pair to 3-6, and it will work.

Some people in old ages, even have used one ethernet 8 wire cable to drive 2 connections by splitting the wires in 2 connectors in each node.

Fully outside any reasonable spec, of course

Comment: I didn't check the positions carefully, but three adjacent to one end and the other not quite to the other end sounds about right.  The desk the drawer was in had an ancient Windows box on it.  (Ancient as in expecting PS-2 mouse and keyboard.)

Comment: Exactly, 1-2 for the green pair and 3-6 for the orange one.